# $z/27=x$, Digital root of the first three digits of the decimal places of x = digital root of z. Why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, modular-arithmetic

I noticed when playing around with numbers that the digital root of the first 3 digits in the decimal portion of the answer to $z/27$ is equal to the digital root of z itself (z is an integer)

For example:

$329833/27 = 12216.037037$

The first three digits of the decimal portion of this answer are 0, 3, and 7. Their digital sum is "1" because 0+3+7=10-->1+0=1

The number we are dividing by, 329833, also has a digital sum of "1". 

329833-->3+2+9+8+3+3=28-->2+8=10-->1+0=1

This is the case for all* integers z.

---

Why is this? Can it be proven algebraically? I discovered this back in 2011 and never thought to ask here until just now.

---

*Exceptions *sort of* include numbers **evenly** divisible by 27, see comments in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1656503/56935) for more: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1656503/56935

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are aiming to prove is that if the remainder of $n$ divided by $9$ is $r$, then the sum of the first three digits divided by $9$ is also $r$.

To use your example, $329833$ divided by $9$ has a remainder of $1$, and in $0.037 \dots$ , note that $3+7$ divided by $9$ is also $1$.

In your other example, $27$ divided by  $9$ is $0$, or $9$ if you prefer. Note that the digit sum of the first three digits of $1.0000...$ is $0$.

Note the fact that $\frac{9k+r}{27}$ is $(0.333\dots)k+\frac{r}{27}$, where  $1 \le r \le 8$

Note that the sum of the first three digits of the decimal representation of $(0.333\dots)k$ are always divisible by $9$.

For $1 \le r \le 8$, Note that the first three digits of $\frac{r}{27}$ are of the form $111m+37k$, where $r$ is $3m+k$ and $1 \le k \le 2$.

This implies the sum of the first three digits of the decimal representation of $\frac{n}{27}$ divided by $9$ is $3m+10k \equiv 3m+k=r \pmod 9$. Our proof is done.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Does this answer your question? Is my proof correct? Any reply would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry was sleeping. Reading now.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I do have a disconnect at one point. You say that r/27 always takes the form of 111m+37k where k is the remainder of r/3 and m is r/3 minus k. How do you know that's always the case? I believe you, I just am wondering how you arrived at that haha

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw If $r$ is $3m+k$, note that $\frac{r}{27}$ is $\frac{m}{9}+\frac{k}{27}$. Since there are no carries(is that the right word?), we can way that  $\frac{m}{9}=(0.111\dots)m$ or $0.mmm\dots$ and that $\frac{k}{27}$ is $(0.037037\dots)k$, so that is why the first three digits are $111m+37k$.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true for $z=27$:

$$\frac{27}{27} = 1.00000000,$$ so the digital sum of the decimal portion is $0$. On the other hand, the number we are dividing, $27$, has a digital sum of $9$.

Comment: Good catch! +1 —— It actually *is* [half] true for 27/27 because the answer is not only 1.00000 but is also 0.999999 since they are one in the same. And 9+9+9=27-->2+7=9 but yes, numbers evenly divisible by 27 are the only exception.